# Erro ao adicionar plataforma android no cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou tentando criar um projeto com o cordova.

Já tenho tudo instalado, npm, cordova sdk do android e etc..

Quando eu crio um projeto nos diretórios do meu pc, tudo funciona normalmente.

```
cordova create teste br.com.anderson Teste
cordova platform add android
cordova run android
```

Mas quando eu tento rodar isso dentro de uma unidade de rede mapeada da esse erro na hora de adicionar a plataforma:

```
U:\app1.0\app>cordova platform add android
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: br.com.anderson
        Name: Anderson
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-22
Copying template files...
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT):platforms\android\.gitignore

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Anderson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente verificar se na configuração do samba o arquivo **.gitignore** não está vetado.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Isso resolveu o meu problema!

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma pesquisa rapida e encontrei um post similar [Link pro post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566641/error-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-1), destacaram que o problema pode ser apenas com o firewall, tente verificar isso ai.

Espero poder ter ajudado com algo.

Abraço

Comment: Não resolveu, obrigado por tentar ajudar.